# The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue. symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, migration, command

when i try to migrate the command  symfony console make:migration  doesn't work and it returns the error : The metadata storage is not up to date, please run the sync-metadata-storage command to fix this issue.

so to solve the problem , I've tried all solutions I could find in different forums and tutos but this last didn't succeed

using bin/console doctrine:migrations:sync-metadata-storage command.

using bin/console bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata command

setting .enf database_url to DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/ecommerce?serverVersion=10.4.24

When I use the doctrine:migrations:sync-meta-storage command, it throws the same exception.

also a tried to clean the cache with command  php bin/console cache:clear.

finally i played my last card Downgrading doctrine/migrations to 3.5.2

but bothing has worked !!!!

Comment: have you tried to delete the cache manually?

Comment: yeah i tried  delete manually the cache in /var/cache folder but infortunatly it doesn't work